# Which is the correct relative error?

Tags: numerical-methods

Which is the correct relative error? 
$$
r_1=\frac{|p_n-p|}{|p_n|}
$$
or
$$
r_2=\frac{|p-p_n|}{|p|}
$$

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_error#Definitions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $p$ is the exact solution and $p_n$ is a numerical approximation, the absolute and relative errors are defined as
$$\text{err}_\text{abs} := |p_n-p|$$
and
$$\text{err}_\text{rel} := \frac{\text{err}_\text{abs}}{|p|} = \frac{|p_n-p|}{|p|}$$
So $r_2$ is correct.

Comment: Thank you. But why does Brian Bradie in A Friendly Introduction to Numerical Analysis on the topic of rootfinding methods write the first stopping condition?

Comment: Basically, as $p_n\to p$, $r_1\to r_2$. It might be easier to compute the error (i.e. faster) or sufficient...

Answer (score 0):

Given some value $u$ and its approximation $u_{approx}$ the definition of elative error is 
$$\frac{|u-u_{approx}|}{|u|}$$
 So if your $p_n$ is the approximation of $p$ in your question the relative error is $r_2$